# Service Fabric Rollback via the SF Explorer

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

I can rollback (or upgrade to previous version) via powershell. For example, if the application was upgraded from "v1" to "v2". To rollback, then the command:

```
Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationTypeVersion v1 <other args>
```

Is the rollback available in SF explorer? I am not able to find the option.

Comment: No. Just do it through powershell

Answer (score 0):

No it is not available from the UI. It can happen automatically or you can do it via powershell

You can create a instance of the old version then delete the newer version your. However you cant create the application with the same name so I am not sure it is a safe rollback